# Distinct in XMLAGG function in oracle sql

Tags: oracle

problem in avoiding duplicates using XMLAGG function

A table which is having multiple records. where each record has one column contains repetitive date. 
Using XMLAGG function in the following sql

```
select col1, col2, XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, colname || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()')
from table
group by col1, col2
```

i get the following output

```
col1      col2      col3
hareesh  apartment  residential, commercial, residential, residential
```

But i need the following output as

```
col3 : residential, commercial.
```

Anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT col1, col2, XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, colname || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, colname FROM table)
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Comment: How can you select `col1, col2` from `(SELECT DISTINCT colname)`??